# Node modules and package-lock.json files are not showing in my folder after installing the built in moodules

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I was trying to install express module in my folder and i runned the cammand in terminal then it is showing me it has been installed successfully but the problem is node_modules and package-lock.json files are not showing in my folder am unable to setup the server. what would be the solution?

I have tried to get the solution from chatgpt but didn't get the right solution.

that error is showing now
C:\Users\91626>npm install -g npm@8.6.0
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules.npm-QXjMEw5N
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules.npm-QXjMEw5N'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules.npm-QXjMEw5N'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.npm-QXjMEw5N'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\91626\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-08-30T07_05_51_937Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Can you update the question with what you have done so far clearly? Have you completed the node installation and npm initializing (npm init) part? Did you get any errors?

Comment: When I am installing modules in the terminal it shows the package looking for funding but the modules are not coming in the folder Also the package-lock.json, i ran the command npm update after that I faced all the problems.

Comment: Still, the question is not clear. When you run `npm update` command it will update all the packages in your project directory. If you run `npm fund` it will list all the packages you have installed that were created by companies or organizations that need money for their IT projects.  Did you use `npm init` before updating?

Comment: Hi, please read [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). All the error lines are messed up. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can try to solve this issue:

Preperation:

1. Make sure you don't have any npm related files (`package.json`, `package-lock.json` etc.) open in your editor. So that the process and your current editing process are not overlapping.
2. Make sure you have permissions to write and read on file system on the folder you are working. You may need to run your editor and/or command line tool with administrative permissions.

Clean-up:

We can clean-up previous npm related files and cache to make sure we can start from completely clean surface. So we don't have any trouble with previous error prone project setup.

1. Delete `node_modules` folder and delete `package-lock.json` file.
2. Run the following command to clean npm cache: `npm cache clean --force`

After the preparation and possible clean-up:

1. You should always initialize your node.js projects by initializing npm. To fo that run the command: `npm init`
2. Install packages you need.
3. If you got warning about out of date npm while installing packages, you should update npm using the following command: `npm install -g npm@latest`